# decimal to binary converter c++?

Tags: c++, binary, decimal

```
int inputNumber=0;
int divisionStore=0,modStore=0;
vector<int> mainVector;

cout << "\nEnter a Number to Convert to Binary.\n" << endl;

cin >> inputNumber;

do
{
    modStore=inputNumber%2;
    inputNumber=inputNumber/2;
    mainVector.push_back(modStore);

}while(inputNumber!=1);

for (int i=0;i<mainVector.size();i++)
{
    cout<<endl<<mainVector[i]<<endl;
}
```

Seems like there is a logical error but I cant find whats wrong with it? The program does not print the correct conversion as it seems like the loop ends before it can push the last number.

Comment: What results were you expecting and what results did you get?

Comment: So, have you tried using a bit of "tracing" - print the number as it is being divided down... [I can see exactly what is wrong, but you learn more from actually working it out than me telling you]

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I was hoping to get 101 when the input was 5, but seems like it went the wrong way and showed only 10

Comment: @MatsPetersson I tried to go through the input with pen and pencil, havent been able to find anything. But I guess somebody just answered what was wrong.

Comment: Using pen and paper is a good way, but you do of course have to take into account the fact that you may not DO exactly the same thing that the computer does. Paul R has the right answer - you need to stop when inputNumber is 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to change:

```
}while(inputNumber!=1)
```

to:

```
}while(inputNumber!=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the STL - i.e. bitset

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/to_string/

Probably do it in a couple lines of code!

Comment: its a class project and using STL is a must unfortunately.

Comment: @user2086751 - perhaps you need to rephrase that comment (and learn the use of apostrophes)

Comment: it's not probably, it's exactly two lines : 
`bitset<some_size> mySet(myInt);
string v = mySet.to_string();`

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier - A couple is two. You get the +1 for being correct

Comment: haha sorry, I'm not a native speaker and in my mind, when people say "a couple", I always see it like "some"

Answer (score 0):

Seams to be a very complicated and inefficient way (if I don't misunderstand you). You are probably looking for bit-manipulation operators, not /, % etc. If you really want to stick it in a vector this should do it:

```
while (inputNumber) {
  mainVector.push_back(inputNumber & 1);
  inputNumber >>= 1;
}
```

Note however that this will put the least significant bit at the beginning of the vector, may not be what you want but looks like it is what your code is trying to do as well.

Comment: the code you posted will generate *identical* compiled code on any decent compiler. and `>>= 1` is a bit more compilcated than `/= 2`.

Comment: I agree, the compiler should be able to optimize the code. Interestingly enough gcc version 4.6.1 appears to add a few instructions if I change the >>= 1 to a /= 2 and another few if I change the & 1 to % 2. At least on -O2 optimization level.

Answer (score 0):

I answered similar question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621225/c-decimal-to-binary-without-arrays/16621684#16621684), I used recursion function

```
void decimal_to_binary(int decimal)
{
    int remainder = decimal % 2;
    if (decimal < 1)
        return;
    decimal_to_binary(decimal / 2);
    cout << remainder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`inputNumber%2` is the least significant bit, so your vector will contain the bits in reversed order. Simply loop the vector in reversed order.

`while(inputNumber!=1)` - You have to loop while `inputNumber!=0`, otherwise you won't process the last bit.

Comment: yeah, I did reverse it before printing. Reversing wasn't my main concern so didn't post the `.reverse()` here.

Answer (score 0):

```
  #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
    int x,bin;
    x=0 ,bin=0;
           int ar[10000];
           cout<<"Enter Decimal Number "<<endl;
            cin>>x;
        int n=0;
            while(x>0){
                bin=x%2;
                x=x/2;
                ar[n]=bin;
                n++;
                }

cout<<endl;
n=n-1;

    for(n;n>=0;n--){
cout<<ar[n]; }
cout<<endl;

return 0;
}
/* Try this */
```